# Desktop Search API

Tags: asp.net, search

I'm working on adding a desktop search ability to my asp.net application, what do you think is the best API to implement that ? I thought about Windows Desktop Search but I didn't find any resource to learn how to add it to my asp.net application, can you help me?

**Edit: The search should happen on a root folder which is located on server side.**

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have a lot of problems with this because web applications, by design, are restricted from accessing the local system by the web browser.  If this was not the case, websites you visit would be able to manipulate files stored on your hard drive!  Let's not get crazy here...

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript), for instance.

I'm not an expert in this arena, but basically if you want your search to run out of a web browser, I'm guessing you'll have to look into writing a browser plugin.

Edit: If you want to search the web server local storage, that is a different issue and I don't have an answer for you offhand.

Answer (score 0):

If you're for server-side files, would [Directory.GetFiles()](http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/) work for you?  Or are you looking to search the content of files, not just their names?